# Plunker with AngularJS and Typescript possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, plunker

I have some code I would like to ask questions about on stackoverflow. The code is written in AngularJS with Typescript, and does manipulation and watching of the $location.hash. I now have the code on github at https://github.com/svdoever/AngularJS-bookviewer. Is it possible to have this code, preferably without the compiled Typescript files, up at http://plnkr.co?

I read at https://twitter.com/filearts/status/290961349092208642 that Typescript should be suported on http://plunkr.co.

Edit:

Solution by Bassarat to add a gh-pages branch to the git repository did the job. See comments on his answer.

Comment: Just follow the link on the tweet, fork the Plunk and add Angular?

Comment: @Anzeo: And if you follow the link in the tweet you can see that the typescript code does not work. It looks like the typescript code is never compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't supported by plunker. But I tend to use http://typescript.io/ when I need third party lib support (e.g. angularjs). Otherwise I just stick with TypeScript Playground http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

## Update

You can use TypeScript anywhere you like using https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script (plunker sample : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script#plunker)

That said many playgrounds now support TypeScript natively *including plunkr* : https://github.com/ggoodman/plunker-run-plugin/blob/master/README.md (just put `"use typescript";` at the top of your file and add a `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: Hi Basarat, problem is that I need multiple files. Both mentioned solutions don't support that feature. The case I have is https://github.com/svdoever/AngularJS-bookviewer. There are so many questions I have about this code, but I don't know how to put it in a single Typescript/Html/Css file. Is a github repository and a live running site on Azure the best way to ask questions about it, or would you suggest another approach?

Comment: @SergevandenOever checkout github pages: http://pages.github.com/ all you need to do is create a branch gh-pages and your index.html will automatically be accessible at https://svdoever.github.io/AngularJS-bookviewer

Answer (score 7):

You can use [TypeScript Compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile) to transform your TypeScript files into JavaScript.

Reference your TS files like this:

```
<script type="text/typescript" src="app.ts"></script>
```

And add these two JS files at the end of the HTML body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//niutech.github.io/typescript-compile/js/typescript.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//niutech.github.io/typescript-compile/js/typescript.compile.js"></script>
```

[Kos Prov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2942409/kos-prov) created a working TypeScript Plunker **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2hn5Vy3UQCA7KqRZZIq?p=info)**.

## Update

You can use [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to load TypeScript files, although you'll need to manually bootstrap Angular.

http://plnkr.co/edit/kFsJ7q?p=preview

Comment: TypeScript Compile has not been updated in a long time

Comment: Your update was just what I was looking for.. forked it to setup a base TS + Angular + Kendo Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ixYVzt?p=preview. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use https://stackblitz.com/ instead, all live examples on angular.io use stackblitz now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cloud 9 or Codio

https://c9.io

https://codio.com/

You can clone projects from github.

It is like an IDE and you will get a terminal. It has node installed.

I tested in cloud 9, but codio is similar you can use it too

You can run this command to install typescript

```
npm install -g typescript
```

then you can compile your .ts file from the terminal.

lets say that you have a file

```
hello.ts
```

you compile it using the following command

```
tsc hello.ts
```

If you are facing issues with compiling, please check the directory where your file is at.

Comment: This has nothing to do with creating a quick, on-the-web prototype in the way that you can with Plunker and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/NqELPE?p=preview

Here's a simple Hello World app that my colleague wrote that uses Typescript and Angular2

Simply use the Plunker tool for including packages and it works fine:

`<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.25/angular2.dev.js"></script>`

Comment: No, this doesn't compile TypeScript into JavaScript. It has pre-compiled files that were simply copied and pasted into plnkr. If you modify the .ts file in the plnkr, the .js file is not updated.

Comment: Not an answer to the question