# Benchmark path-planning algorithm written in TypeScript in the browser

Tags: algorithm, typescript, benchmarking, pastebin, browser-testing

I have 3 typescript algorithms I need to benchmark in the browser. I tried area51, area51 is only for JavaScript. I also found a pastebin:

```
//pastebin.com/gCs9CB5F
```

Can someone give me a hint how to run a benchmark on TypeScript?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit. It's not clear at all what you are asking.

Comment: Depending on the environment your using you can compile the typescript into plain javascript which you should be able to use in area51 and other places

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Transpile via the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)
- Benchmark via [benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/docs)

For example, this TypeScript code:

```
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}

console.log(add(2,2)); // 4
```

Can be benchmarked after transpilation as follows:

```js
var bench1 = new Benchmark(
  {'fn':add, 'cycles':0,'count':1,'name':'bench1','async':true}
);

function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

function log(result){console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.target.stats)))};

bench1.on('complete', log);
bench1.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.2/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

**References**

- [niutech/typescript-compile: Automatically compile TypeScript to JavaScript on the fly](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile)
- [basarat/typescript-script: Script tag support for TypeScript](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script)
- [Is there a way to get TypeScript to transpile in Plunkr on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529588/)
- [TypeScript: Getting started : Notepack](http://jakub.marchwicki.pl/posts/2016/01/31/typescript-getting-started/)
- [TypeScript: Our Type of JavaScript | Linux.com | The source for Linux information](https://www.linux.com/blog/learn/2017/7typescript-our-type-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is typescript, so start writing your performance test in typescript. The only ting typescript could affect performance that I can think of is which  `target` do you use in tsconfig.json - probably es5 will be slower than es2018 because of pollyfills. Also language features that don't exists in js standard would be interesting to test, for example https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html